# Ionic serve failing after a refresh

Tags: node.js, ionic3, ionic-serve

I'm currently working on an `Ionic 3` project and when I do `ionic serve` then the project runs but after first time loading the `ionic serve` stops with the following errors:

> (node:487) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel
>   closed
>   (node:487) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

And one more error sometimes:

> [10:03:47]  lint finished in 18.51 s  events.js:182
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:607:25)

My npm version is `5.6.0`

> Update:
>   considering [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17858) I've considered downgrading my npm version to 5.2 but the error  still presists

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue somehow.Don't know what solved it but here are my step.

First removed `node modules` folder using `package-lock.json` file.

```
remove ./node_modules/ws folder
run $ npm install ws@3.3.2
```

This [issue helped me](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-crash-on-save/115615/45) this may be a temporary solution but hope it helps.
**A short note:** I had already downgraded my npm so that might be a requirement as well